# When is Personal Finance and Money going to get out of beta?

Tags: discussion

I think there's a really strong community already and don't see why the developers aren't moving it out of beta. Are there any more milestones to be met?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent question! A few stats:

- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721/personal-finance-and-money
- http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true

Also refer to Robert's post here:

https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/what-happens-now

But if that's TL;DR, in general ...

1. Share great questions and answers
   http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/
2. Vote, vote, *vote*
   http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/
   https://money.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters
3. Love and reward your new users for being awesome!
   https://money.stackexchange.com/review
   https://money.stackexchange.com/users

Comment: Looks like you don't like me, I had posted the same question in December 2010, and did'nt get a reply :) ... http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/180/any-idea-when-this-site-will-come-out-of-beta

Comment: @dheer robert answered that one, so it got answered!

Comment: I looked at Robert's post and the blog post.  I think we are at a different spot than Writers when they posted that question.   We have 11 3K+ rep users (need 5).  We have 19 2K+ rep users (need 10).  We have 98% answered rate, reasonable traffic (1.5K/day).   Search engine traffic is 81%.  Every metric is "excellent" and would lead me to think we would graduate very soon, except the number of questions/day (5.9 today).  Is that the only metric you are waiting on?

Comment: @Alex B If you look at the [list of sites by traffic](http://stackexchange.com/sites?sort=traffic), you may see a pattern.  I *suspect* Money will happen after OnStartups.  Note this not official policy or anything, just me guessing.

Comment: I'm guessing that the site needs to hit 2K+ a day to get out of beta.